# data grid view select multiple cells

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am able to select a single cell from a data grid view but I am trying to see if it would be possible for me to select multiple cells at once and use that data. to create a chart using C#

Comment: You looking form [MultiSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect.aspx) property?

Comment: I have tried a lot of way but they all in turn only allow me to select multiple cells using the ctrl button i want the users to be able to select multiple without this

Comment: So mention that you want **SELECT MULTIPLE CELLS WITHOUT CTRL KEY**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to select DataRow, this `DataRow` contains  `Cells`  property

```
 var cells = DataGridView.Rows[index].Cells;
```

Code Sample

```
    public DataControlFieldCell GetCellByName(GridViewRow Row, String CellName)
    {
        foreach (DataControlFieldCell Cell in Row.Cells)
        {
            if (Cell.ContainingField.ToString() == CellName)
                return Cell;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In order to permit multi select , you define `DataGridView.MultiSelect` property

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect.aspx

You can also use

```
DataGridName.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode.aspx

Comment: i want the user to select this form the actual form and not using hard code./

Comment: i added another link about permit Multi select

Comment: but through the use of this i still have to select multiple using the ctrl button and thats when i can select multiple is there any other way without pressing ctrl button.

Comment: Ypu can also use DataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

Comment: but i dont need them to select that i only want to pick certain cells

Comment: in this case you can use DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect

Comment: is it possible for me to add check boxes to add the data.. so mutiple rows can be used